# How Can i Read a unread SMS on uwp?

Tags: c#, sms, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I need some help. I have this code:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageStore store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var msgList = store.GetMessageReader();
IReadOnlyList<Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage> a = await msgList.ReadBatchAsync()
```

And I read all SMS with this

```
foreach (var item in a)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Body);
}
```

How can I read only unread SMS? I mean only read new SMS and afterwards change the status to 'read'.

Question is for Uwp Win 10..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ChatMessage class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642160)

IsRead property is Read-only. That mean you can only check is message already readed. But you can't set that message is been readed or unreaded

```
       foreach (Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage item in a)
        {
            if (item.IsRead) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Body);
        }
```

Comment: I can to read a New SMS but I don't Know How Can I check this message already Readed....I use ite.IsSeen=True But don't save this status